# Rolling cube animation. How to?

Tags: animation

Can anyone tell the way how to animate a rolling cube? Without bones. In Maya, for example, its quite easy to animate pivot point (origin) or use locators (empties), but in blender it seems to be a problem. There is a Pivot constraint, but besides that snaping doesn't work, it works in a weird way on its own.
here is example scene - https://yadi.sk/d/T5aIx1qnkk473

Comment: Do you mean a cube "rolling" on a floor? like a square wheel?

Comment: yeah, definitely

Comment: Rigs are something to help with manual animation. If you don't want bones, it can be done with empties and constraints also. Is rig such this: https://media.giphy.com/media/26tPsgLJdnLbw3CQ8/giphy.gif something that you would consider as solution?

Comment: Combined with this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21406/7777 it will make a nice rolling animation controlled with a path.

Comment: Well, sort of. It looks kinda complex, but if there are no other ways to do it then it would be great to see how that rig was made.

Comment: Example with the ball is not the same, as rolling cube, Cube doesn't spin around its center. Try to roll a brick instead of cube to feel the difference

Comment: seems I have found the answer. I couldnt find it in a list when I asked this question.   http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/how-to-animate-a-cube-pivoting-more-than-once-without-affecting-its-original-po?rq=1  but could u give a link to that cube rig?

Comment: Posted a driver based approach in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/how-to-animate-a-cube-pivoting-more-than-once-without-affecting-its-original-po  ... although this q appeals as more appropriate to me as it's "rolling" on a floor like a square wheel.

Comment: If this q is given a reprieve and lives, can my answer above be moved to this one?