Constraint which finds "lowest" point on object even as it rotates?
I need to drag an object across a floor (without physics) which is rotating and thus have different parts of its mesh (or at least a plane representing a simplified version of it) as its lowest point.

Using constraints only, I can't really figure it out. I suspect I have to use the floor constraint and shrinkwrap constraint, and possibly two different empties, but haven't figured out the combination yet.
Anyone understand what I'm getting at and know how to solve this?

hello could you please show a picture of your object, or a storyboard?

@moonboots sure, added a sketch now

Would several custom pivot points parented between each others such as in this tutorial would work for you?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1_6l9vxyKs

maybe parent your object to an empty, and parent the empty to another empty? Move the empty 1 for the first movement, then move empty 2 when the object is supposed to tilt? Edit: I guess it's the solution linked by Jag JB

I assume you can't use physics then bake the result to keyframes?

No, I want this "live" and dynamic. I've gotten as far as discovering that you can use two shrink wrap constraints at the same time, but the moment my object moves too far away or rotates a certain way, the empty snaps to the floor because it's "outside" of the mesh I use to represent the bottom of my object...

I'm also now trying two empties, one at each extreme each with a floor constraint, parented to the empty I am controlling the animation with, and then attempting to place a new empty between those two at the floor and parent my object to that, but it still sinks into the floor in certain scenarios...

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42144/rolling-cube-animation-how-to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/how-to-animate-a-cube-pivoting-more-than-once-without-affecting-its-original-po https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143046/how-can-i-roll-a-cube-around-its-edges-with-armatures https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69731/rotate-a-cube-on-a-plane-using-drivers https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119677/how-can-i-rig-a-cylinder-so-that-when-its-rotated-its-end-cap-will-not-penetrat

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos but I didn't want to use drivers or bones. Thanks for nothing, I guess.

You didn't mention avoiding drivers or bones in your post. In the linked posts there are also solutions using parenting and constraints, besides drivers and handlers. If non of those solutions work for you please edit your post and clarify what your constraints are and why those don't satisfy your needs, so it can be repened.
