# Why is my mesh not fully taking the location constraint serious?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I animated the ROOT bone, and added a 'Limit Location' on the BottomRR set to be fixed on Z=0. But somehow the ROOT bone forces the mesh to dip under Z=0 during the rotation (while the bone BottomRR stays perfectly in place). How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: How is your mesh parented to the bones? How are the bones parented to each others? What is your final animation? Does the mesh continue to rotate?

Comment: My mesh is parented with empty groups. BottomRR is a child of a child of a child of ROOT. The animation you see is the whole animation (I'm creating lots of short rotations to export to Unity). When I want to continue the rotation, I just make a new action -> put the 'influence' of the constrain of BottomRR to 0.0 and activate the constrain of TopRR For example.

Comment: if that was the only animation it would be easy, you'd make the BottomRR the parent of the whole mesh and it would its rotation axis, so I guess it's not the only animation and you need it to rotate along the 3 other corners?

Comment: Exactly. I need the armature to rotate my object around all it's edges.

Comment: it seems easy but I'm not sure it's easy thing to do, there was a question quite similar few months ago but I don't know how to find it, here is a close question though, maybe it will answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143046/how-can-i-roll-a-cube-around-its-edges-with-armatures

Comment: @moonboots, thanks for digging this one up, but ironically it's and old question from myself ;-). Haha/The answers (which where great though) led me to this new point.

Comment: oh ok ah ah, you're still stuck in the same problem

Comment: Yep, at least I know how to rotate the mesh over its edges, but now I'm dealing with this sort of loose transform issue. It's just like in real life: Parents and children, always a conflict somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its due to the default f-curve created on the ROOT bone, change its type (channel) to 'linear Extrapolation' that could fix it, but you may have to add one of the 'modifiers' to it.
Also see this
[Rotate a Cube on a Plane Using Drivers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69731/rotate-a-cube-on-a-plane-using-drivers)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. With the linear Extrapolation, the flow of the curve is no changing, since the curve already was linear. Also the (F-Curve) Modifiers kind of accomplish the same. The link you shared is apart from briljant and way beyond my league also just not helpful in my situation because I cannot work with drivers since I'm exporting my armature to Unity.

Comment: BTW thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm adjusting the F-Curve of the Root bone manually now. It's not perfect and clean, but it will do the job for 98%.